# bread made with egg safe to leave outside?

Tags: food-safety

I have some bread that has egg in it.  Safe to leave the bread at room temp after baking?  Im asking because I wouldn't leave scrambled eggs at room temp but is bread ok?

Comment: Scrambled eggs are muuch different from using eggs in bread dough. Unless you're talking about having egg slices in a sandwich. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Luciano The OP was explaining why leaving bread made with eggs at room temperature seemed like a bad idea.

Comment: @Sneftel I figured so, but didn't want to assume anything.

Comment: Would you leave a cake out? - Yes. Cakes are made with eggs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Food safety categorizes each food on its own. You cannot take the categories of the ingredients that went in ("flour is shelf stable, eggs need refrigeration...") and decide on the shelf stability of the product based on the ingredients. For detailed information on the basics of how food safety works, read our tag wiki on food safety, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Breads can be stored on the counter, no matter what they were made with.